# UIScrollView contents not laying out correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I've spent two days trying to get this to work and no luck.  I've spent a lot of time researching on here and Google and whilst there's some info about adding UIImageViews into UIScrollViews, there doesn't seem to be much about other content such as UITextFields & UILabels.

Referencing the code below, I have a few issues:

1. The `contentView` within the `myScrollView`: Even though the `contentView` has `backgroundColor`, constraints etc, the `contentView` does not seem to show up correctly, yet the subviews added to it do show up (see attached screenshot).
2. The `UITextFields` added into the `contentView` of the `scrollView` do not layout correctly despite constraints being set.  As can be seen in the screenshot, textfields positioned outside of those views with similar constraints DO get laid out correctly - for example the orange textfield.
3. The vertical scrolling doesn't work to show (in this case, the `thirdTextField`, i.e. the teal textfield) isn't showing and can't scroll to it.  Strangely, if I type inside the `secondTextField` i.e. the red text field, it will expand in size and continue to grow and ends up automatically activating the horizontal scrolling for the `UIScrollView`.  Also, don't understand this as its embedded in a `containerView` that has constraints that just seem to be ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies in advance for the 101 type question.

All below is done programatically rather than via storybaords.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var myScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view =  UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return view
    }()

    lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    var firstTextField = UITextField()
    var secondtextField = UITextField()
    var thirdTextField = UITextField()
    var fourthTextField = UITextField()

    var firstLabel = UILabel()
    var secondLabel = UILabel()

    var aButton = UIButton()

    var keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add first label
        view.addSubview(firstLabel)
        firstLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        firstLabel.text = "Yellow Label"

        // Layout first label
        firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        firstLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        firstLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        // Add first textfield
        view.addSubview(firstTextField)
        firstTextField.backgroundColor = .orange
        firstTextField.placeholder = "Orange TextField"

        // Layout first text field
        firstTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
        firstTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        firstTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        firstTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // Add scrollView
        view.addSubview(myScrollView)

        // Layout scrollview
        myScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        myScrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        myScrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        myScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200.0).isActive = true

        // Add ContentView inside scrollview
        myScrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        // layout contentview
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

        // Add secondTextfield - inside contentview
        contentView.addSubview(secondtextField)
        secondtextField.backgroundColor = .red
        secondtextField.placeholder = "Red TextField"
        secondtextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // Layout secondtextField - inside contentview
        secondtextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondtextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        secondtextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        secondtextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        // Add thirdtextfield - inside contentview
        contentView.addSubview(thirdTextField)
        thirdTextField.backgroundColor = .brown
        thirdTextField.placeholder = "Brown TextField"
        thirdTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // Layout thirdtextField - inside contentview
        thirdTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            // Placed 500 below secondtextfield to use through vertical scrolling
        thirdTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondtextField.topAnchor, constant: 500).isActive = true
        thirdTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        thirdTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        // elements outside of scrollview
        // add fourthtextField
        view.addSubview(fourthTextField)
        fourthTextField.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        fourthTextField.placeholder = "Teal Textfield"
        fourthTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // layout fourthtextField - over the top of the scrollview (for testing/modelling purposes)
        fourthTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        fourthTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
        fourthTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        fourthTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        // Add second label
        view.addSubview(secondLabel)
        secondLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        secondLabel.text = "Green Label"

        // Layout of second label
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -150).isActive = true
        secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        // Add button
        view.addSubview(aButton)
        aButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        aButton.setTitle("A Button", for: .normal)

        // Layout button
        aButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        aButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
        aButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        aButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        // Add Target to BUtton
        aButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: @SPatel Thanks. I could but how I’m planning to use this in the long run, will make it more complicated. Plus I would like to actually learn and understand why this isn’t working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shurtugal's answer is partially correct -- you need a `bottomAnchor` on `thirdTextField` to give `contentView` some height:

```
thirdTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

See the comments to that answer for some additional discussion.

However, I'm adding this answer as a tip. You may find it much easier to work with constraints and auto-layout if you group the constraints logically together, as shown in the edited code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var myScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view =  UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return view
    }()

    lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    var firstTextField = UITextField()
    var secondtextField = UITextField()
    var thirdTextField = UITextField()
    var fourthTextField = UITextField()

    var firstLabel = UILabel()
    var secondLabel = UILabel()

    var aButton = UIButton()

    var keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add first label
        view.addSubview(firstLabel)
        firstLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        firstLabel.text = "Yellow Label"

        // Add first textfield
        view.addSubview(firstTextField)
        firstTextField.backgroundColor = .orange
        firstTextField.placeholder = "Orange TextField"

        firstTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // Add scrollView
        view.addSubview(myScrollView)

        // Add ContentView inside scrollview
        myScrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        // Add secondTextfield - inside contentview
        contentView.addSubview(secondtextField)
        secondtextField.backgroundColor = .red
        secondtextField.placeholder = "Red TextField"
        secondtextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // Add thirdtextfield - inside contentview
        contentView.addSubview(thirdTextField)
        thirdTextField.backgroundColor = .brown
        thirdTextField.placeholder = "Brown TextField"
        thirdTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // elements outside of scrollview
        // add fourthtextField
        view.addSubview(fourthTextField)
        fourthTextField.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        fourthTextField.placeholder = "Teal Textfield"
        fourthTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar

        // Add second label
        view.addSubview(secondLabel)
        secondLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        secondLabel.text = "Green Label"

        // Add button
        view.addSubview(aButton)
        aButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        aButton.setTitle("A Button", for: .normal)

        [firstLabel, firstTextField, myScrollView, contentView, secondtextField, thirdTextField, fourthTextField, secondLabel, aButton].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // firstLabel 100-pts from top, 20-pts on each side
            firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            firstLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            firstLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20),

            // firstTextField 150-pts from top, 20-pts on each side
            firstTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150),
            firstTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            firstTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20),

            // myScrollView 20-pts from bottom of firstTextField
            // 20-pts on each side
            // 200-pts from bottom of view
            myScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            myScrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            myScrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            myScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200.0),

            // contentView (subview of myScrollView) 20-pts on each side
            // this will automatically define the scrollView's .contentSize
            // however, it does NOT control the SIZE of contentView
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // secondtextField (subview of contenView) 100-pts from top, 20-pts on each side
            secondtextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            secondtextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            secondtextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

            // secondtextField (subview of contenView) 500-pts from top of secondtextField (should probably be from bottom of secondTextField)
            // 20-pts on each side
            // (end up being placed 500 below secondtextfield to use through vertical scrolling)
            thirdTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondtextField.topAnchor, constant: 500),
            thirdTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            thirdTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

            // constraints which define the SIZE of contentView...

            // if we want contentView to fit the width of myScrollView (with 20-pts "padding" on each side)
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -40),
            // thirdTextField bottom 20-pts from contentView bottom (this will define contentView's height)
            thirdTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),

            // fourthTextField 300-pts from bottom of firstTextField, 10-pts on each side
            fourthTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 300),
            fourthTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            fourthTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),

            // secondLabel 150-pts from bottom of view, 20-pts on each side
            secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -150),
            secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

            // aButton 100-pts from bottom of view, 20-pts on each side
            aButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),
            aButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            aButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

        ])

        // Add Target to BUtton
        aButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() -> Void {
        print("button tapped")
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

after scrolling:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Whilst the other answers also worked, I agree with you.  The two key points here are:  
  
1. The `contentView` needs a width constraint so linking it to the width of the parent `scrollView` works and is the neatest.  
2. Adding the `bottomAnchor` constraint to the `thirdTextField` but linking this to the `contentView` is the key and is neat.  There were other suggestions that required calculations once the views laid out in `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but yours is the neatest and cleanest.  
  
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -40.0).isActive = true
```

In this way the contentView/scrollView will know that the scrolling is vertical and:

```
thirdTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

because contentView needs to have constraints for all the heights to make a proper layout. 
Now you will see the blue contentView, for the rest of the layout... idk man, you need to check the values.

Comment: The second part of your answer - `thirdTextField.bottomAnchor...` - is correct, but the first part is not. If `contentView` is a subview of the scroll view, you *definitely* do not want to constrain it to `view` (the scroll view's superview).

Comment: trust me, it works when you want to have a vertical scrolling. And without those constraints, contentView does not know what width to take. But maybe I'm missing something, how do you set a width for contentView?

Comment: The `contentView`'s ***width*** is controlled by the leading and trailing constraints of ***its*** subviews (the OP has set them on `secondtextField` and `thirdtextField`). Just as the `contentView`'s ***height*** is controlled by ***its*** subviews (as you noted in your answer, the OP needs `thirdTextField.bottomAnchor...`). Now, the text fields widths are - based on the OP's code - controlled by their intrinsic size, which is based on the text field's text. If he wants the text fields, and the blue `contentView`, to fit the width of the scroll view...

Comment: ... (with 20-pts "padding" on each side) then he should also add `contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true`.